# How to unset a key on a $_POST array?

Tags: php

I have some code to intercept a POST request, and then based on the value of another key, to unset a different key. However that part isn't working.

I know this is not the ideal method of doing this, but the script is an add-on to an existing open source platform, so I'm unable to modify existing scripts.

```
if($_POST['id']['txt_10'] == "Initials"){
    unset($_POST['id']['id[8]']);
}else if($_POST['id']['txt_10'] == "Name"){
    unset($_POST['id']['id[1]']);   
}
```

However this code doesn't do anything and doesn't even display an error. Using a `var_dump($_POST['id']);` I can see the key is still set.

--

This is the var_dump of the $_POST['id'] array:

```
array(7) {
    ["txt_10"]=> string(4) "Name" 
    ["txt_11"]=> string(0) "" 
    [1]=> int(72) 
    [4]=> int(0) 
    [8]=> int(170) 
    ["txt_7"]=> string(7) "wefgweg" 
    [5]=> int(0) 
}
```

Comment: You should never modify `$_POST` directly. Instead grab a copy in a variable and manipulate that. As per your code, I don't see anything wrong with it. Perhaps a `var_dump` of the post itself would help.

Comment: change it to  unset($_POST['id']['id'][8]);

Comment: @Andrew I am unable to do that for reasons above.

Comment: if you show us the var_dump of $_POST it will be easier to adress the issue

Comment: @NanaPartykar That's incorrect.

Comment: @zedd I have updated the question with the Var Dump.

Comment: How will i know that you posted wrong array. I thought multidimensional array @user2924019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unset($_POST['id'][8])` would be the correct way to adress it

Comment: You're right. I have no idea where I got the id[] part from. That works. Many thanks.